# Finding 1-hop, 2-hop, ..., k-hop neighbors in Python using Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, dijkstra

I am trying to find 1-hop, 2-hop, and if needed, k-hop neighbors of some specific nodes (lets say `l` nodes) in a graph using `nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length`.

1. what is the time complexity according to each step (1-hop, 2-hop, ...), and
2. is there any faster algorithm?

Comment: Is your question concerning the implementation of the algorithm in `networkx` or about the algorithm as such?

Comment: I am implementing the algorithm in 'networkx' now and my question is about the complexity. There is another question if there is any other built-in library or algorithm faster than the one I am using. Thank you @sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at unweighted graph, you can use breadth-first-search and the time complexity for small k should be on average `O(<k>^k)`, where `<k>`is the average degree of the regarded graph.

If you want to calculate multiple distances in a weighted graph, you should rather use the [multi_source_dijkstra_path_length](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.multi_source_dijkstra_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.multi_source_dijkstra_path_length). I am not sure which runtime this algorithm has, but probably it is an improvement in comparison to multiple runs of Dijkstra, which has `O(|V|log(|V|)+|E|)` (depending on the implementation).

If you want to use a threshold the maximal distance in a weighted graph, it probably depends on the weight distribution on your edges and the minimal or average edge weight, which influences the number of nodes needed to calculate to reach the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sparky05. What if the regarded graph is weighted and the search criterion is a threshold **T** instead of the number of hops?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe using Dijkstra something like O(j<k>+j*log(|V|)), where j=ceil(T/<w>) and <w> is the average weight.

Comment: Thank you @Sparky05, your explanations helped a lot.